# Describe all the one dimensional complex representation of the cyclic group $C_n$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Describe all the one dimensional complex representation of the cyclic group $C_n$ . Which ones are inequivalent?

attempt: Any 1 dimensional representation is irreducible.  Every complex representation of $C_n$ can be expressed as a direct sum of irreducible reprentations. And by the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, $C_n$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic groups.

Can someone please help me? I dont really know what I have to show for the inequivalent part.   Any feedback would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The irreducible complex representations of $C_n$ are exactly the $1$-dimensional. Each one of them is specified by the requirement that a generator $c\in C_n$ acts (upon the elements of the $1d$ complex vector space) through multiplication by an $n$-th root of unity. Thus, if $\rho:C_n\rightarrow Aut V$ is the representation, then $$\rho(c)\cdot v=e^{2\pi i\frac{k}{n}}v, \ \ \ k=1,2,...,n$$
for a generator $c\in C_n$ and for any $v\in V$. In this way, each $n$-th root of unity provides an irreducible, complex representation of $C_n$ on $V$. These representations are mutually inequivalent. Thus, there are exactly $n$ inequivalent, irreducible, complex representations.

Comment: why are they mutually inequivalent ?

Comment: because a similarity transformation (at the level of complex numbers this is: multiplication and division by the same number) cannot change the value of a complex number: $x^{-1}zx=z$.

Comment: @KonKan Hi. May I know why the sentence "Each one of them is ... etc." holds? I am new to this material. I am comfortable using $G$-module language instead. Thank you so much.

Comment: @KonKan I have been asked to classify all non-isomorphic simple $C_3$-module which is similar, but how do I translate the language? What I do: Let $C_3=\{e,g,g^2\}$ and $V$ be the module. I know $V$ should be one dimensional, hence $V=span\{v\}$ for some $v\in V$. The $C_3$ acts on $V$, so we should have $g.v$=$kv$ for some complex number $k$. What is next? I have no idea what we are going to do. Thank you for the guidance.